# Prove that $\{H_1,\dots,H_k\} \models F$ if and only if $(H_1 \land \dots \land H_k) \rightarrow F$ is tautology

Tags: logic

Assume that $H,F$ are formulas. How to prove that $\{H_1,\dots,H_k\} \models F$ if and only if $(H_1 \land \dots \land H_k) \rightarrow F$ is tautology. My intuition is that's right, but I don't know how to prove this in a clean and precise manner.

Definition $\models$: $ H \models F$  means that every interpretation suitable for both $H$ and $F$, which is a model for $H$ is also a model for $F$.

Comment: Is it propositional logic? How is $\models$ defined?

Comment: @Berci I added my definition.

Comment: Consider the simple case of $k=2$. If $(H_1 \land H_2) \to F$ is taut, this means that the formula is true for every truth assignment. Thus, what happens with a truth assignment that satisfies $(H_1 \land H_2)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can write "$X$ is a tautology" as "$\emptyset\models X$", with the empty set of preconditions.

So we have:

$$\emptyset\models (H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_k) \to F$$

Introduce preconditions on both sides:

$$\{H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_k\} \models  (H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_k) \wedge ((H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_k) \to F)$$

Simplify the implication:

$$\{H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_k\} \models  F$$

Answer (score 0):

To say that $\{H_1,\dots,H_k\}\models F$ is to say that there is no interpretation making all the $H_i$'s true and making $F$ false. To say that $(H_1\land\dots\land H_k)\to F$ is  tautology means, thanks to the truth table for implication, that there is no interpretation making $H_1\land\dots\land H_k$ true and making $F$ false. By the truth table for conjunction, these are the same.